# Can we convert a const vector<string> to vector<string> using const_cast?

Tags: c++, vector, casting, type-conversion, const-cast

Please forgive me if it is very basic. I like to use **const_cast** for the conversion. If it is possible can anyone please share the example. Other way which I'm avoiding is to iterate const vector and insert its content into a new vector.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the original then why do you need the `const_cast`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const_cast` doesn't introduce undefined behaviour (i.e., it's safe to use), as long as the variable you're `const_cast`ing wasn't originally defined as `const` or if it was originally defined as `const` you're not modifying it.

If the above restrictions are kept in mind then you can do it for example in the following way:

```
void foo(std::vector<std::string> const &cv) {
  auto &v = const_cast<std::vector<std::string>&>(cv);
  // ...
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccc3bb21cc3fcc9d)

Comment: It isn't UB either if you don't modify the casted variable.

Comment: Thanks. This is what i looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Make a non-const copy of a vector given a `const std::vector<X>&` you can just write

```
void foo(const std::vector<std::string>& src) {
    std::vector<std::string> localcopy(src);
    ... localcopy can be modified ...
}
```

if however you only need to access a local read-write copy and not the original src the code can be simplified to

```
void foo(std::vector<std::string> localcopy) {
    ...
}
```

i.e. you just pass the vector **by value** instead of by reference: the vector that the caller is passing will not be modified by the callee because a copy will be made implicitly at call time.

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful. Is there any way we can remove the const flag from src(way we do using const_cast)? so that we can use the same src variable as a non cost vector. I'm just thinking if  there is a way to avoid a copy in localcopy variable and use the same src variable?